# Ionic changing icons based on loan status

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

.html file

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let loan of loans" [routerLink]="['/detail']">
        <ion-label>
            <ion-icon [name] = 'status.icon'></ion-icon>
            <p>Username: {{loan.username}}</p>
            <h3>Status: {{loan.status}}</h3>
            <h3>Due Date: {{loan.duedate | date:'d MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
            <h3>Loan Items: {{loan.items.length}}</h3>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

what should be in my .ts file to change the icons depending on the status of the loan?

The name for the icons are 'checkmark-circle' for approved, 'close-circle' for rejected and 'cloud-circle' for pending.

Comment: You could use the *ngIf directive on your ion-icon tags. If the if statement evaluates to true, create ion-tag where icon is x.

Comment: You also use Ternary Operators like: `[name] = loan.status == 'approved ' ?  checkmark-circle'  :  loan.status == 'rejected'  ?  'close-circle '  :   'cloud-circle' ` something like this.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Your sample should be an answer. There is no need to do something in .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of status and pass them to a method for some dynamic scenario like:

```
status: {approved: 'checkmark-circle', rejected: 'close-circle', pending: 'cloud-circle'}
```

but to be simple for now u can check it as static value.

.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let loan of loans" [routerLink]="['/detail']">
        <ion-label>
            <ion-icon [name] = 'getIconName(loan.status)'></ion-icon>
            <p>Username: {{loan.username}}</p>
            <h3>Status: {{loan.status}}</h3>
            <h3>Due Date: {{loan.duedate | date:'d MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
            <h3>Loan Items: {{loan.items.length}}</h3>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

.ts file

```
getIconName(status: string): string{
    switch(status){    // instead of switch u can filter an array of status and value
      case 'approved': 
        return 'checkmark-circle';
      case 'rejected': 
        return 'close-circle';
      case 'pending': 
        return 'cloud-circle';
    }
}
```

also u can do it inline as '[Najam Us Saqib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5909026/najam-us-saqib)' said in comment